# Application Bot Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So this code sends a DM to a user asks the user some questions my goal then is to send the application back to a specific channel not sure how to do that any help i know you have to user the channel id but not sure how to compile all the answers and then send them back to the specific channel?

````
  let userApplications = {}

  bot.on("message", function(message) {
    if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;

    let authorId = message.author.id;

    if (message.content === "%apply") {
        console.log(`Apply begin for authorId ${authorId}`);
        // User is not already in a registration process
        if (!(authorId in userApplications)) {
            userApplications[authorId] = { "step" : 1}

            message.author.send("```We need to ask some questions so  we can know a litte bit about yourself```");
            message.author.send("```Application Started - Type '#Cancel' to cancel the application```");
            message.author.send("```Question 1: In-Game Name?```");
        }

    } else {

        if (message.channel.type === "dm" && authorId in userApplications) {
            let authorApplication = userApplications[authorId];

            if (authorApplication.step == 1 ) {
                authorApplication.answer1 = message.content;
                message.author.send("```Question 2: Age?```");
                authorApplication.step ++;
            }
            else if (authorApplication.step == 2) {
                authorApplication.answer2 = message.content;
                message.author.send("```Question 3: Timezone? NA, AU, EU, NZ, or Other? (If other, describe your timezone)```");
                authorApplication.step ++;
            }
            else if (authorApplication.step == 3) {
                authorApplication.answer3 = message.content;
                message.author.send("```Question 4: Do you have schematica?```");
                authorApplication.step ++;
            }

            else if (authorApplication.step == 4) {
                authorApplication.answer4 = message.content;
                message.author.send("```Thanks for your registration. Type %apply to register again```");
                //before deleting, you can send the answers to a specific channel by ID
                bot.channels.cache.get("616852008837709844")
                  .send(`${message.author.tag}\n${authorApplication.answer1}\n${authorApplication.answer2}\n${authorApplication.answer3}\n${authorApplication.answer4});
                delete userApplications[authorId];
            }
        }
    }
  });


}


module.exports.help = {
    name: "app"
}```
````

Comment: Do you want to send the answers back to the channel the user originally wrote `%apply` in? Or to a specific channel for you to see?

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start here because you are keeping the state of all users applying in a `userApplications` object. Because you want to preserve the user's answers, you can simply use this state object - stuff the user's answers in there and use them when you need to.

For example:

````
bot.on("message", function(message) {
  if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;

  let authorId = message.author.id;

  if (message.content === "%apply") {
      console.log(`Apply begin for authorId ${authorId}`);
      // User is not already in a registration process    
      if (!(authorId in userApplications)) {
          userApplications[authorId] = { "step" : 1}

          message.author.send("```We need to ask some questions so  we can know a litte bit about yourself```");
          message.author.send("```Application Started - Type '#Cancel' to cancel the application```");
          message.author.send("```Question 1: In-Game Name?```");
      }

  } else {

      if (message.channel.type === "dm" && authorId in userApplications) {
          let authorApplication = userApplications[authorId];

          if (authorApplication.step == 1 ) {
              authorApplication.answer1 = message.content;
              message.author.send("```Question 2: Age?```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }
          else if (authorApplication.step == 2) {
              authorApplication.answer2 = message.content;
              message.author.send("```Question 3: Timezone? NA, AU, EU, NZ, or Other? (If other, describe your timezone)```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }
          else if (authorApplication.step == 3) {
              authorApplication.answer3 = message.content;
              message.author.send("```Question 4: Do you have schematica?```");
              authorApplication.step ++;
          }

          else if (authorApplication.step == 4) {
              authorApplication.answer4 = message.content;
              message.author.send("```Thanks for your registration. Type %apply to register again```");
              //before deleting, you can send the answers to a specific channel by ID
              bot.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL_ID_HERE")
                .send(`${message.author.tag}\n${authorApplication.answer1}\n${authorApplication.answer2}\n${authorApplication.answer3}\n${authorApplication.answer4}`);
              delete userApplications[authorId];
          }
      }
  }
});
````

There are a number of easy, immediate improvements you can make to this - for example, store the answers in an array instead of separate properties. But without knowing your experience level I won't introduce code that you may not understand easily.

Comment: Trying to run your code but its not seem to be working

Comment: @JamesLewis Are you getting any error? Did you replace `CHANNEL_ID_HERE` with your desired channel ID?

Comment: Yes errors https://hastebin.com/unosixisad.js this is my whole code. Not sure why its not working.

Comment: @JamesLewis My network blocks that site. Can you edit the errors into the question or add them here as a comment?

Comment: @JamesLewis Apologies, I just spotted a missing ` in the code. I imagine it was causing at least one of your errors. On the `.send` line at the end there's no closing ` for the template literal. Try the edited code.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Comment: @JamesLewis The channel was not found. Your channel ID is incorrect or the bot doesn't have access to that channel.

Comment: Bro i got it to work! Thanks so much question anyway to format the bot response to look like this? https://ibb.co/8jCRgwS if your pc blocked it it's in a embed with the question followed by the users response!

Comment: @JamesLewis You can use the properties `authorApplication.answer1` through `answer4` however you like. Feel free to create an embed and insert those properties where the answers should appear. If you run into issues that you can't figure out I suggest asking another question. Glad you got it to work!

Comment: @JamesLewis I suggest asking a new question so others can pitch in. :)

Comment: nvm got it to work thanks for all the help! @klaycon

Comment: One last thing please how do i get the property authorApplication.answer1 to fit in a embed? This is nott working..```.addFields(
      {name: 'question 1', value: 'authorApplication.answer1'},
    )```

Comment: @JamesLewis Posting an answer is not an invitation to use me as a debugging resource for multiple hours, please ask another question if you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

````
  let userApplications = {}

  bot.on("message", function(message) {
    if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;

    let authorId = message.author.id;

    if (message.content === "%apply") {
        console.log(`Apply begin for authorId ${authorId}`);
        // User is not already in a registration process
        if (!(authorId in userApplications)) {
            userApplications[authorId] = { "step" : 1}

            message.author.send("```We need to ask some questions so  we can know a litte bit about yourself```");
            message.author.send("```Application Started - Type '#Cancel' to cancel the application```");
            message.author.send("```Question 1: In-Game Name?```");
        }

    } else {

        if (message.channel.type === "dm" && authorId in userApplications) {
            let authorApplication = userApplications[authorId];

            if (authorApplication.step == 1 ) {
                authorApplication.answer1 = message.content;
                message.author.send("```Question 2: Age?```");
                authorApplication.step ++;
            }
            else if (authorApplication.step == 2) {
                authorApplication.answer2 = message.content;
                message.author.send("```Question 3: Timezone? NA, AU, EU, NZ, or Other? (If other, describe your timezone)```");
                authorApplication.step ++;
            }
            else if (authorApplication.step == 3) {
                authorApplication.answer3 = message.content;
                message.author.send("```Question 4: Do you have schematica?```");
                authorApplication.step ++;
            }

            else if (authorApplication.step == 4) {
                authorApplication.answer4 = message.content;
                message.author.send("```Thanks for your registration. Type %apply to register again```");
                //before deleting, you can send the answers to a specific channel by ID
                bot.channels.cache.get("616852008837709844")
                  .send(`${message.author.tag}\n${authorApplication.answer1}\n${authorApplication.answer2}\n${authorApplication.answer3}\n${authorApplication.answer4});
                delete userApplications[authorId];
            }
        }
    }
  });


}


module.exports.help = {
    name: "app"
}```
````

Comment: There we go this is my exact code that im getting errors on!

Answer (score 0):

I am creating this discord.js application bot, but I want to add more commands for applications. For example, I want a command !apply1 and command !apply2. When I copy the code, paste it again, change the name of the command, and type the command, it sends two or three questions instead of one. What should I change?

If you didn't understand and want to check what I am talking about join this fake discord server: https://discord.gg/fVsQaa6 (It sends 2 questions per time, I want to send 1 by 1. Also, it sends the answers to the same channel for both of them, I checked if the channel id is correct and it is.)